# Name of this flower?

Tags: flowers, flowering

i'd like to know the name of this flower.

[image]

Comment: where is this flower located? try to give us as much information as possible - will make it easier for someone to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [Dutchman's Pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristolochia_littoralis) (aka Calico Flower); the genus has over 500 species, but I'm pretty sure this is it.

[image]